# NavigationStackView with .searchable modifier works as expected, NavigationSplitView is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

NavigationStackView with .searchable modifier is working as expected.

```
struct NavStackListSearchView: View {
    @State private var items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"]
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<String> = []
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var filteredItems: [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return items
        } else {
            return items.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
        }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(item) {
                        Text(item).font(.title3)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in
            selectedItems = []
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationSplitView** with .searchable modifier is **crashing**:

```
struct NavSplitListSearchView: View {
    @State private var items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"]
    @State private var selectedItems: Set<String> = []
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var filteredItems: [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return items
        } else {
            return items.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
        }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if selectedItems.isEmpty {
                Text("Pick an item")
            } else {
                Text("\(selectedItems.first ?? "--no item--")")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in
            selectedItems = []
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the crash in NavSplitView:

1. launch the app
2. click on "Item3"
3. go back (if in compact mode)
4. search for "3"
5. click on only item shown, that is "Item3"
   --> crash

Why? What do I miss? How can I solve this issue?
Target iOS 16.2, Xcode 14.2

Comment: I believe this is a SwiftUI crashing bug. I filed a Feedback with Apple (FB12059008).

Comment: FYI, seems that iOS 17 beta fixes this crashing bug.